# parse array in string form in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, string-parsing

I am trying to process a json document from 3rd party api. the data return is in a string format and lokks something like this:

```
{
   "response":{
      "field1":7,
      "field2":0,
      "records":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "title":[
               "cyx"
            ],
            "doc1":[
               "1",
               "2"
            ],
            "doc2":["\n\t        [\n\t        \t\"1\",\n\t            \"2\",\n\t        ]\n\t    "],
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

when I try to process the doc2 it returns the string like this: `[ "1", "2", ]` instead of returning an array as in demo for doc1.
when I try to use the JSON.parse(), the application throws an error.

here is a simple demo of the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/harpalshergill/39acf4dn/24/

I am wondering how to parse this array without removing whitespace, \n, \t character manually?
thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no `doc1` in the code. Could you please add this field.

Comment: The problem is the trailing `,` causing `JSON.parse` to throw an error. The `doc2` value is not valid JSON as shown. If this is the real data, it is being generated incorrectly.

Comment: @crashmstr you are right. JSON.parse works if that "," is not there in doc2

Answer (score 0):

You can replace characters like in the example

```js
var body = " {\"Warranty\": [ \n { \n \"Name\": \"test\", \n \"Type\": \"test2\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"Test6\", \n \"Type\": \"test7\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"test9\", \n \"Type\": \"test10\", \n \"Miles\": \"10000\", \n } \n ]} ".replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/,}/g,'}');
var object = JSON.parse(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach:

```js
const doc2 = ["\n\t        [\n\t        \t\"1\",\n\t            \"2\",\n\t        ]\n\t    "];
const result = doc2.toString().replace(/[^\w\r\n]+/gm, "").trim().split('\n');


// result =  ["1", "2"]
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/2kyp6aow/